¿Cómo puedo optimizar una inserción de datos en mi base de datos de Django?
Muy buenas tardes a todos, espero me puedan colaborar.
Soy un desarrollador muy junior todavía y estoy implementando en un proyecto de prueba el uso de hojas de Excel para insertar n cantidad de datos en una base de datos.
La parte del frontend la implemento con VueJS y el uso de axios para mandar la petición y el backend esta implementado con Django donde uso su ORM para la gestión de base de datos.
La inserción de datos se hace a una tabla llamada productos y la lógica es que si la referencia (Que es única y es su identificador) existe entonces se edita el producto en cuestión, si no existe se crea.
El punto es que se me pidió optimizar la inserción de datos de un archivo de Excel que contiene 10.000 registros y que todos estos registros puedan ser ingresados en la base datos.
En la función poseo unas ciertas validaciones para poder mostrarlas en una tabla como lo muestro a continuación

Me gustaría recibir ayuda de como poder optimizar el código en Python ya que tiene que hacer en total mas de 9.000 bucles donde se ha demorado mas de 2 minutos para completar los 10.000 registros

    datosJson = request.POST.get('datos')
    print(datosJson)
    datos = json.loads(datosJson)
    errores = []

    for index, dato in enumerate(datos):
        print(dato)
        diccionario = {}
        erroresDato = []
        producto = None

        if 'referenciaProducto' in dato and dato['referenciaProducto']:
            producto = Producto.objects.filter(borrado = False, referencia = dato['referenciaProducto']).values('id').first()
            if not producto:
                diccionario['referenciaProducto'] = dato['referenciaProducto']
                erroresDato.append('Referencia Producto Invalida')
        else:  
            diccionario['referenciaProducto'] =  ''
            erroresDato.append('Referencia Producto Vacia')


        if 'codigo' in dato and dato['codigo']:
            if dato['codigo'] is None:
                diccionario['codigo'] = ''
                erroresDato.append('Codigo Vacia')
        else:
            diccionario['codigo'] = ''
            erroresDato.append('Codigo Vacia')


        if 'cantidad' in dato and dato['cantidad']:
            if dato['cantidad'] is None:
                diccionario['cantidad'] = ''
                erroresDato.append('Cantidad Vacia')
            else:
                if not esNumero(dato['cantidad']):
                    diccionario['cantidad'] = dato['cantidad']
                    erroresDato.append('Cantidad no es numérico')
                elif isnan(float(dato['cantidad'])): 
                    diccionario['cantidad'] = dato['cantidad']
                    erroresDato.append('Cantidad no es numerico')
        else:  
            diccionario['cantidad'] = ''
            erroresDato.append('Cantidad Vacia')


        if diccionario:
            if not 'codigo' in diccionario:
                diccionario['codigo'] = dato['codigo']

            if not 'referenciaProducto' in diccionario:
                diccionario['referenciaProducto'] = dato['referenciaProducto']

            if not 'cantidad' in diccionario:
                diccionario['cantidad'] = dato['cantidad']

            erroresFila = ", ".join(erroresDato)

            diccionario['erroresCampos'] = erroresFila

            diccionario['posicion'] = index + 2
            errores.append(diccionario)
            continue


        codigo = Inventario.objects.filter(borrado=False, codigo=dato['codigo']).values('id')
        print(codigo)
        if codigo.exists():
            inventario = Inventario.objects.get(borrado = False, codigo = dato['codigo'])

            inventario.producto_id = validator(producto['id'], inventario.producto_id)
            inventario.cantidad = validator(int(dato['cantidad']), inventario.cantidad)
            inventario.save()

        else:
            Inventario.objects.create(
                codigo = dato['codigo'],
                producto_id = producto['id'],
                cantidad = dato['cantidad']
            )

    response = {"mensaje": "Creación exitosa", "Errores": errores}
    return JsonResponse(response) ```


Te recomiendo utilizar [introducir la descripción del vínculo aquí][Pandas] ya que tiene estrategias para hacer bulk inserts. Talvez este enlace te de una luz: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48006551/speeding-up-pandas-dataframe-to-sql-with-fast-executemany-of-pyodbc
